# Read object from binary stream in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have an object of primitive data types (actually integers of different sizes). It is packed the same way as in pure C. What is idiomatic way to read such an object from binary stream (actually a socket) or byte array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a stream:

```
DataInputStream(inputStream).use {
    it.readByte()
    it.readInt()
    it.readLong()
}
```

From a byte array:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).also {
    it.get()
    it.getInt()
    it.getLong()
}
```

Comment: What is **bytes**??

Comment: `bytes: ByteArray`